# How can I combine data from 200 different google spreadsheets to one master google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-addons

I have about 200 google spreadsheets. Each of these google spreadsheet has multiple sheets. I need to gather the data of one of the sheet in all the 200 google sheets to one combine sheets. it is like the data from a specific sheet, specific range need to be combined. I need them to be vertically added to the resulting combined sheet.
I have tried google add on "combine sheets", unfortunately the final product which I am getting is not what I require. from the add on combine sheets, it is adding the data from multiple sheets one below the other horizontally in rows, however, I need them to be added vertically to columns.
is it possible to combine them vertically and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  You need to create a simple use case/example that can be extrapolated to the larger problem.  Does it make a difference if there are 2 spreadsheets or 200?  What is the core problem?  What is the formula you tried that didn't work.

Comment: Hi. I would try `importRange` but even though a limitation on the number of linked spreadsheets has been lifted, users are reported inconsistent results. Also 200 spreadsheets might have an effect on the calculation time. Personally, I think I would go for a script ; you can choose whether/when to update the data (or create an onOpen trigger).